# $SU(2)$ gauge supersymmetric theory and superpotential

Tags: potential, gauge-theory, supersymmetry, non-perturbative

I am currently studying supersymmetry and I came across a superpotential of the following form

$$W=\frac{\Lambda^5}{\bar{Q}Q}+m\bar{Q}Q.$$

The first term is said to appear as a result of non-perturbative effects. What does it mean? What does such a model generally describe and does it have a name? How many vacuums does such a model have?

Comment: Came across where? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic I am reading lecture notes from a professor at my institute. And this superpotential is given there simply as a kind of task. But there is no indication of what this potential is or what it describes.

Comment: It could be an example of a potential studied in dynamical supersymmetry breaking in SUSY QCD, but without more info it's hard to tell.
You could try looking up the original papers and reviews by Seiberg for this topic.

Comment: @Guillaume Trojani thank you very much - this is useful information! All I can add is that the $Q$ and $\bar{Q}$ fields are in the fundamental and anti-fundamental representation of $SU(2)$. I tried to find a vacuum of such potential myself, but I could not

Comment: @Dmitry I don't know if that is so usefull actually. There is a whole industry of looking at different superpotentials and I'm not really working in that area so I'm sorry I can't write a full answer.